# Tkinter ask a string inside a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm trying to run a multi thread application,
each thread is asking for the user to provide a string input after some tasks the thread does.

```
simpledialog.askstring(title, content, parent=window)
```

the problem is that you cannot use the main thread window as the parent window inside a thread because you'll end up with this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: window ".!_querystring2" was deleted before its visibility changed
```

which is logical because the thread and the main thread are not synchronized

after hard research I've ended up with a solution which says
"Create a new TK window instance for the thread"

```
newWin = tk.Tk()
newWin.withdraw() #to make it invisible
simpledialog.askstring(title, content, parent=newWin)
newWin.destroy()
```

which will work for my case if I wouldn't have a main tk window instance inside the main thread.
the destroy method for the "newWin" is causing my main window to be destroyed as well.
and I'll be ended up with this error :

```
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

tkinter isn't a thread safe, and not gives an easy life when using it cross threads.

does anyone have any idea/trick how can I ask a string from a user inside a thread?

Some extra info about my code :
I'm triggering this function by a button click:

```
#tree is a treeview widget
def click(tree):
    threads = simpledialog.askstring("Threads", "How many threads?")
        if threads is not None:
            try:
                threads = int(threads)
                if threads > 0:
                    thread = tm.threadObject(name="checkAccounts", target=checkUsers, args=[tree, threads])
                    thread.start()
#instance passes automatically from the tm.threadObject
def checkUsers(instance, tree, threads):
    for child in tree.get_children():
        while len(tm.threadsManager.getThreads("checkAccountWorker")) >= threads and instance.alive:
print("Sleeping")
            time.sleep(1)
        if not instance.alive:
            break
        item = tree.item(child)
        taskHandler = task.taskHandler(tree, child)
            thread = tm.threadObject(name="checkAccountWorker", target=taskHandler.doAction, args=[taskHandler.CHECK_USER], kill=taskHandler.kill, killargs=[], passInstance = False)
            thread.start()

#part of the doAction code:

def doAction(*args):
    #some code behind
    newWin = tkinter.Tk()
                newWin.withdraw()
                code = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Activation", "Enter recevied code : ", parent=newWin)
                newWin.destroy()
    self.currentStatus = "Entering code"
    mainEvents.updateTreeItem(tree, "status", item, self.currentStatus)


def updateTreeItem(tree, column, item, value):
    key = ""
    for col in tree["columns"]:
        if tree.heading(col)["text"].lower() == column.lower():
            key = col
    if key == "":
        return
    tree.set(item, key, value)
```

It works at the first attempt. but when I click again on the checkUsers button I end up with the error :
"Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread"
I honestly don't know why

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have multiple windows? Can't you have string `form` inside the main widget window?

Comment: Yes, it is neccessary. Because you need to ask a string in a specific time and the thread have to wait for the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Every time button is clicked we create new `threading.Thread` object and start it. It's target will be the `askString` function.
- In the `askString` we create new window and add to it widget `simpledialog.askstring`.

This code below will do the trick:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
import threading

def askString():
    new_window = tk.Tk()
    new_window.withdraw()
    print(simpledialog.askstring(title = "String input", prompt = "What's your Name?:", parent = new_window))
    new_window.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text = "Click me!", command = lambda: threading.Thread(target = askString).start())
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

> How you get the value from the function to your GUI is up to your
> implementation (framework).

Comment: Or if you wanna to work it differently just say I can rewrite it :)

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but as I mentioned before. You can't do destroy on a new tk.Tk because it will effect the root Tk window. so Inside a thread if you call tk.Tk and then destory. and afterwards do again a new tk.Tk and destroy it you will end up with the error "Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread" which will crash the root window and terminate your application

Comment: My code doesn't throw any errors and it certainly doesn't affect the main window because it is in the new thread and it is completely different widget. Try my code yourself and you will see it will work.

Comment: okay after checking your code.. It seems that it doesn't throw the error I've mentioned.. which is weird. Inside my thread If I'm using your solution I'm ending up with an error of "Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread". I would give you a +1. but it doesn't solve my specific problem so I can't accept it as the right answer. If you know what can cause the error I'm mentions and how can I use your code without ending up with the "Tcl_AsyncDelete" error I would love to mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Okey great. Then if you provide us with your code I can make it work there too :)

Comment: I think the problem lies in your framework. So I need to get a look at the code.

Comment: Hi dear friend :), thanks so much for your effort. I'll accept your answer anyway because I agree the problem lies somewhere in my code because when I tried to do your code. and even when I tried to complicate it and put it in an async function still it went well. I've updated some details on my code flow. you may check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227753/discussion-between-tyler-perry-and-jakub-szlaur).

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
After some work around I've created my own "getString" window dialog..

code:

```
    @staticmethod
    def getString(title, content):
        topLevel = tk.Toplevel()
        topLevel.title(title)
        topLevel.resizable(False, False)
        strVar = tk.StringVar()
        label = tk.Label(topLevel, text=content)
        label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)

        entry = tk.Entry(topLevel, textvariable=strVar)
        entry.grid(column=0, row=1)
        def close(topLevel):
            if entry.get() != "":
                topLevel.destroy()
        button = tk.Button(topLevel, text="Set", command=lambda: close(topLevel))
        button.grid(column=1, row=1)
        topLevel.lift()
        while(topLevel.winfo_exists()): # wait until topLevel destroyed
            time.sleep(1)
        return strVar.get()
```

It's a bit messy.. couldn't manage to accomplish a cleaner solution but it works.
You can ask for a string inside a thread this way :)
If someone have a nicer way to do so you may suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's multiprocess to work arouond this error.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def askstring_helper(*args, **kwargs):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    result_queue = kwargs.pop('result_queue')
    kwargs['parent'] = root
    result_queue.put(simpledialog.askstring(*args, **kwargs))
    root.destroy()


def askstring(*args, **kwargs):
    result_queue = mp.Queue()
    kwargs['result_queue'] = result_queue
    askstring_thread = mp.Process(target=askstring_helper, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    askstring_thread.start()
    result = result_queue.get()
    if askstring_thread.is_alive():
        askstring_thread.join()
    return result
```

Now you can use askstring in any code just like you would use simpledialog.askstring.